Random generator of SI units
I created the following code to make a siunits+number random generator, but it gives a misaligned  SI units when I want it to be in the same line. How to fix it?
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgf} % For random number generation
\usepackage{amsmath} % For math mode

\begin{document}

% Seed the random generator with the current time
\pgfmathsetseed{\number\pdfelapsedtime}

% Generate a random exponent for scientific notation
\newcommand{\randomscientific}{
    % Generate a random coefficient between 1.000 and 9.999
    \pgfmathrnd \pgfmathparse{1.000 + 8.999 * \pgfmathresult}
    \edef\coefficient{\pgfmathprintnumber[fixed,precision=3]{\pgfmathresult}}
    
    % Generate a random exponent between -99 and 99
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\exponent}{int(-99 + rnd*199)}
    
    % Output the scientific number
    \coefficient \times 10^{\exponent}
}

% Generate a random exponent between -4 and 4 for units
\newcommand{\randomexponent}{
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\exp}{int(-4 + rnd*9)} % Exponents between -4 and 4
    \ifnum\exp=1
      {} % Do not print the exponent if it is 1
    \else
      ^{\pgfmathprintnumber[fixed,precision=0]{\exp}} % Print exponent
    \fi
}

% Generate three unique units from the SI basic units list with exponents
\newcommand{\randomunits}{
    % Define a list of basic SI units
    \def\units{{\text{kg}}{\text{m}}{\text{s}}{\text{K}}{\text{mol}}{\text{A}}{\text{cd}}}

    % Generate three different indices for the units
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\indexa}{int(rnd*7 + 1)}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\indexb}{int(rnd*6 + 1)}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\indexc}{int(rnd*5 + 1)}

    % Ensure that the units do not repeat
    \ifnum\indexb=\indexa \advance\indexb by 1\fi
    \ifnum\indexc=\indexa \advance\indexc by 1\fi
    \ifnum\indexc=\indexb \advance\indexc by 1\fi

    % Print the first unit with a random exponent
    \ifnum\indexa=1 \text{kg}\randomexponent\fi
    \ifnum\indexa=2 \text{m}\randomexponent\fi
    \ifnum\indexa=3 \text{s}\randomexponent\fi
    \ifnum\indexa=4 \text{K}\randomexponent\fi
    \ifnum\indexa=5 \text{mol}\randomexponent\fi
    \ifnum\indexa=6 \text{A}\randomexponent\fi
    \ifnum\indexa=7 \text{cd}\randomexponent\fi

    % Print the second unit with a random exponent
    \ifnum\indexb=1 \cdot \text{kg}\randomexponent\fi
    \ifnum\indexb=2 \cdot \text{m}\randomexponent\fi
    \ifnum\indexb=3 \cdot \text{s}\randomexponent\fi
    \ifnum\indexb=4 \cdot \text{K}\randomexponent\fi
    \ifnum\indexb=5 \cdot \text{mol}\randomexponent\fi
    \ifnum\indexb=6 \cdot \text{A}\randomexponent\fi
    \ifnum\indexb=7 \cdot \text{cd}\randomexponent\fi

    % Print the third unit with a random exponent
    \ifnum\indexc=1 \cdot \text{kg}\randomexponent\fi
    \ifnum\indexc=2 \cdot \text{m}\randomexponent\fi
    \ifnum\indexc=3 \cdot \text{s}\randomexponent\fi
    \ifnum\indexc=4 \cdot \text{K}\randomexponent\fi
    \ifnum\indexc=5 \cdot \text{mol}\randomexponent\fi
    \ifnum\indexc=6 \cdot \text{A}\randomexponent\fi
    \ifnum\indexc=7 \cdot \text{cd}\randomexponent\fi
}

% Print the scientific notation number followed by three SI units with exponents
\[
\randomscientific \cdot \randomunits
\]

\end{document}

Goal: to get a random generator of $x.yzt\cdot 10^{n}$ $A^aB^bC^c$, where A,B,C are different basic SI units (m, s, kg, mol, K, A, cd), or multiples of it, and a,b,c are numbers between -4 and 4 (for instance) in the same line. How to do it and not get multiple lines and spaces in the powers of A, B or C?

doesn't this code give you an error?

Yes, to the level of the editor (Overleaf and/or TexStudio): warning that _ should be in math mode. Also, in separates me lines. Also, it repeats me some units from time to time. I need to know how to avoid them and how to change x by cdots between powers of ten and scientific notation.

you should fix the cause of the errors first. output after an error is not reliable - it is only good for debugging. so you need to do that at as a first step. then, if you still don't get what you want, you worry about the output. I fixed the errors in your code and removed (what I assumed were) spurious spaces and paragraph breaks. but, as Joseph said, it's not really clear what the purpose of your code is.

The purpose of the code is to generate a list of units to be used in my class exercises, I am done with thinking about "putting numbers", so I decided to try to create a code that gives me the numbers and the units. I do know now how to get the powers or the cyphers, but the issues I have are: 1) Repeated basic units, 2) Crosses instead of dots, and some times, the code tell me before compiling _ should be in math mode, but it gives no error. Thanks to you, I solve the issue with spaces but not with repetitions. Goal: to get a full list of e.g., 10 cyphers plus basic SI units for exercises.

You define \indexa, \indexb and \indexc as macros. So they expand to character tokens. They are not count or dimension registers, so TeX cannot \advance them. To do that, you need to assign them to count registers or counters. Since this should be done globally, counters are safer, so I used those.
You also need to remove blank lines from definitions unless you want a paragraph break. Moreover, line endings should be commented to avoid introducing unwanted spaces. (This is not really an issue here because maths mode has its own spacing rules, but it is a bad habit to develop as it will bite you in other cases. And believe me, tracking down a lone uncommented line ending can  mean a long and very tiresome search.)

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgf} % For random number generation
\usepackage{amsmath} % For math mode

\begin{document}

% Seed the random generator with the current time
\pgfmathsetseed{\number\pdfelapsedtime}

% Generate a random exponent for scientific notation
\newcommand{\randomscientific}{%
  % Generate a random coefficient between 1.000 and 9.999
  \pgfmathrnd \pgfmathparse{1.000 + 8.999 * \pgfmathresult}%
  \edef\coefficient{\pgfmathprintnumber[fixed,precision=3]{\pgfmathresult}}%
  % Generate a random exponent between -99 and 99
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\exponent}{int(-99 + rnd*199)}%
  % Output the scientific number
  \coefficient \times 10^{\exponent}%
}

% Generate a random exponent between -4 and 4 for units
\newcommand{\randomexponent}{%
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\exp}{int(-4 + rnd*9)}% Exponents between -4 and 4
  \ifnum\exp=1
    {}% Do not print the exponent if it is 1
  \else
    ^{\pgfmathprintnumber[fixed,precision=0]{\exp}}% Print exponent
  \fi
}

% Generate three unique units from the SI basic units list with exponents
\newcounter{indexa}
\newcounter{indexb}
\newcounter{indexc}
\newcommand{\randomunits}{%
  % Define a list of basic SI units
  \def\units{{\text{kg}}{\text{m}}{\text{s}}{\text{K}}{\text{mol}}{\text{A}}{\text{cd}}}%
  % Generate three different indices for the units
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\indexa}{int(rnd*7 + 1)}%
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\indexb}{int(rnd*6 + 1)}%
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\indexc}{int(rnd*5 + 1)}%
  \setcounter{indexa}{\indexa}%
  \setcounter{indexb}{\indexb}%
  \setcounter{indexc}{\indexc}%
  % Ensure that the units do not repeat
  \ifnum\value{indexb}=\value{indexa}\stepcounter{indexb}\fi
  \ifnum\value{indexc}=\value{indexa}\stepcounter{indexc}\fi
  \ifnum\value{indexc}=\value{indexb}\stepcounter{indexc}\fi
  % Print the first unit with a random exponent
  \ifnum\value{indexa}=1 \text{kg}\randomexponent\fi
  \ifnum\value{indexa}=2 \text{m}\randomexponent\fi
  \ifnum\value{indexa}=3 \text{s}\randomexponent\fi
  \ifnum\value{indexa}=4 \text{K}\randomexponent\fi
  \ifnum\value{indexa}=5 \text{mol}\randomexponent\fi
  \ifnum\value{indexa}=6 \text{A}\randomexponent\fi
  \ifnum\value{indexa}=7 \text{cd}\randomexponent\fi
  % Print the second unit with a random exponent
  \ifnum\value{indexb}=1 \cdot \text{kg}\randomexponent\fi
  \ifnum\value{indexb}=2 \cdot \text{m}\randomexponent\fi
  \ifnum\value{indexb}=3 \cdot \text{s}\randomexponent\fi
  \ifnum\value{indexb}=4 \cdot \text{K}\randomexponent\fi
  \ifnum\value{indexb}=5 \cdot \text{mol}\randomexponent\fi
  \ifnum\value{indexb}=6 \cdot \text{A}\randomexponent\fi
  \ifnum\value{indexb}=7 \cdot \text{cd}\randomexponent\fi
  % Print the third unit with a random exponent
  \ifnum\value{indexc}=1 \cdot \text{kg}\randomexponent\fi
  \ifnum\value{indexc}=2 \cdot \text{m}\randomexponent\fi
  \ifnum\value{indexc}=3 \cdot \text{s}\randomexponent\fi
  \ifnum\value{indexc}=4 \cdot \text{K}\randomexponent\fi
  \ifnum\value{indexc}=5 \cdot \text{mol}\randomexponent\fi
  \ifnum\value{indexc}=6 \cdot \text{A}\randomexponent\fi
  \ifnum\value{indexc}=7 \cdot \text{cd}\randomexponent\fi
}

% Print the scientific notation number followed by three SI units with exponents
\[
    \randomscientific \cdot \randomunits
\]

\end{document}

Alternative approaches:

use expl3 (and don't worry about blank lines and spaces!); or
use the new integer evaluation methods (which are basically friendlier wrappers around expl3 so you don't have to see the thing's innards); or
use TeX count registers, but be careful in choosing names.


I'd use siunitx for the printing plus some expl3 for the coding. One possible approach
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand \unitsdemo { }
  {
    \group_begin:
      \sisetup
        {
          minimum-decimal-digits = 3
        }
      \use:e
        {
          \qty{\fp_eval:n{round(rand() * 10, 3)}E\fp_eval:n{randint(0,99)}}
            {
              \__unitsdemo_unit:
              \__unitsdemo_unit:
              \__unitsdemo_unit:
            }
        }
    \group_end:
  }
\cs_new:Npn \__unitsdemo_unit:
  {
    \int_case:nn { \int_rand:n { 7 } }
      {
        { 1 } { \kilogram }
        { 2 } { \metre }
        { 3 } { \second }
        { 4 } { \mole }
        { 5 } { \ampere }
        { 6 } { \kelvin }
        { 7 } { \candela }
      }
    \tothe { \int_rand:nn { -4 } { 4 } }
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\unitsdemo

\end{document}

We could tighten up to deal with repeated units, power-zero, etc., but it's not clear what is wanted.
You can adjust the output appearance using the standard keys: I suspect you might want
\sisetup{
  inter-unit-product = \ensuremath { { } \cdot { } },
  quantity-product = \ensuremath { { } \cdot { } }
}

based on your example.

I get times instead a dot in the scientific notation, also someties I get repeated units...Can it be solved too?

If you don't mind using lualatex you can get Metapost to do the random parts.

Compile this with lualatex to get a PDF as shown above.
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{
  inter-unit-product = \ensuremath { { } \cdot { } },
  quantity-product = \ensuremath { { } \cdot { } },
  round-mode = places,
  round-precision = 3
}
\usepackage{luamplib}
\begin{document}
\begin{mplibcode}

vardef shuffle @#(expr n) = 
  save t, r;  string t;
  for i = n downto 0:
    r := floor uniformdeviate i;
    t := @#[r]; @#[r] := @#[i]; @#[i] := t;
  endfor
enddef;

string siunits[], exponents[];
i = -1;
for t = "kg", "m", "s", "K", "mol", "A", "cd":
  siunits[incr i] = t;
endfor
i := -1;
for t = "^{-4}", "^{-3}", "^{-2}", "^{-1}", "", "^2", "^3", "^4":
  exponents[incr i] = t;
endfor

vardef random_unit = 
  shuffle siunits(6);
  shuffle exponents(7);
  "\qty{" 
  & decimal (uniformdeviate 20 - 10) 
  & "e" 
  & decimal (floor uniformdeviate 120 - 60) 
  & "}{"
  & siunits[0] & exponents[0] & "."
  & siunits[1] & exponents[1] & "."
  & siunits[2] & exponents[2] & "}"
enddef;

beginfig(1);
  for i=1 upto 4:
    label.rt(TEX(random_unit), (0, 20i));
  endfor
endfig;
\end{mplibcode}
\end{document}

Note
The shuffle macro can shuffle any array, but you should declare the temporary variable t appropriately, and you need to tell it how many items there are to shuffle.  The shuffling algorithm is based on D. E. Knuth:  The Art of Computer Programming, Vol 2, Third edition.  Section 3.4.2, Algorithm P, pp 145. Addison-Wesley, 1997.  ISBN:  0-201-89684-2.

I am trying to test several options to the moment,...since my computer is a minipc with bad chip/graphics (by Christmas I will try to get something better, specially for compiling heavy code in python and animations). I am looking to the code to add the the multiples/submultiples of the SI in the random code, i.e., (da,h,k,M,G,T,P,E,Z,Y,R,Q) and (d,c,m,μ,n,p,f,a,z,y,r,q) previous to the basic S.I. units to get the most general S.I. units. I suppose that delete a "unit" when the exponent is zero is difficult (I am returning to programming due to AI, i learned f90 in the early 2000s).

@riemannium that's why I left 0 out of the list of exponents, and why I put "" for 1.
